# How to pass a textbox value to beginform routevalues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.beginform

I have a textbox in my mvc view.I want to pass the textbox data in beginform route values.how to do that?

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "InwardDetail", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset style="width:80%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:20px;min-width:60%">
         <div>
            <table class="tableView" style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DevExpress().Label(lbl=>{
                       lbl.Name = "lblFromDate";
                       lbl.Text = "From Date";
                   }).GetHtml()
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBox("txtFromDate", value: DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), htmlAttributes: new {id="fromDate", Class="textbox",style="width:70px"})
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DevExpress().Button(but=>{
                       but.Name = "butView";
                       but.Text = "View";

                       but.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
                                       }).GetHtml()
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="9">
                        @Html.Partial("InwardDetailPartial")
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string fDate)
        {
            _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
            blInwarddetail = new InwardRegisterBL(_unitOfWork);
            var result = blInwarddetail.GetInwardList(fDate);
            return View("Index", result);
        }
```

If I click Button the values should be passed to controller.

Comment: You can't unless you used javascript/jquery to update the forms `action` attribute. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to bind the grid based on the route values

Comment: What grid? Show some code so we can understand what your trying to do

Comment: You only have one input in your form (a textbox). How do you expect to post back 4 values (your method has 4 parameters)?

Comment: Now I changed my Code.But I cant pass the textbox value to my Controller Action

Comment: Your control is named `txtFromDate` so the parameter needs to be `string txtFromDate`. But its looks like its a date so it should be `DateTime txtFromDate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `@Html.TextBox("txtFromDate", ..)` means you generate an input with `name="textFromDate"`. When you submit a form, the name/value pairs of the forms controls are sent - in your case it would be `txtFromDate: 27/06/2015`.

But the method your posting to does not have a parameter named `txtFromDate` (only one named `fDate`). You need to change the method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string txtFromDate)
{
  ....
}
```

However there are numerous issues with your code that you should address

First you should create a view model to represent what your wanting to display/edit in a view

```
public class FilterViewModel
{
  [Display(Name = "...")] // some user friendly display name
  [Required(ErrorMesage = "Please enter a valid date")]
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Note from the code you have shown it appears your entering a date, not a string so the property should be `DateTime` (not `string`). This also ensures that you get client and server validation for the property. I also give your properties a more descriptive name that `fDate` (I can't begin to guess what that might mean - maybe FinishDate?)

In the GET method

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
  FilterViewModel model = new FilterViewModel();
  model.Date = DateTime.Today;
  return View(model);
}
```

And in the view

```
@model yourAssembly.FilterViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  ....
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "textbox" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Date)
  ....
}
```

Note that you are now strongly binding to your model property. The second parameter specifies the format string. There seems no need to override the `id` property (which will be `id="Date"`), and to add a class name use `@class = ".."`. Note also since you are adding a class name, you should remove `style="width:70px"` and instead use css. You should also remove the table elements. Html table elements are used for tabular data, not for layout.

And finally the post method will be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FilterViewModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(model);
  }
  // model.Date will contain the value enter by the user
}
```

Finally I would question if this really should be a POST. Form the code, you don't appear to be changing any data and perhaps this should be `FormMethod.GET`? Or better, use ajax to update the current page based on the filter.